# The word ‘dryly’ as an adverb

Tags: adverbs

What is the correct use of the word *dryly* in the following sentence?

> You said that very dryly.

Is *dryly* correct in this context?

Comment: The question title refers to *dry* as an adjective, but then your question body is about *dryly*, which is an adverb. Just a remark. :-)

Comment: You might also have said it very *drolly*, and to be honest I think a lot of people wouldn't hear and/or understand the difference.

Comment: I see you edited the title already, but this isn't actually the word *dry* as an adverb, it is *dryly* as an adverb.  Some adjectives do get used as adverbs informally, like "he got out of there quick"; this is different obviously.

Comment: @Kosmonaut Yes I realised my mistake with the title after CesarGon mentioned it. I believe Jimi Oke was good enough to edit it

Comment: @Chris: CesarGon's comment was about the use of the word "adverb" vs. "adjective".  I was talking about "dry" vs. "dryly".  Twice you mention "dry", but you are asking about "dryly".  I guess I'll fix it myself.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

My Dictionary says:

> **dryly** |ˈdrīlē| (*also drily*)
>   adverb 
>   **1** in a matter-of-fact or ironically humorous way : *“How very observant,” he said **dryly**.* 
>   **2** in a dry way or condition : *Evans swallowed **dryly**.*

I also found it can be a synonym of "being cold" and not just "ironic" and "sarcastic".

Answer (score 2):

Yes, that is correct. 'Dryly' is the adverbial form of the adjective 'dry', and the adverb is called for in this case, since it modifies the verb.