# What is a dry sense of humor?

Tags: meaning

What does a *dry* sense of humor mean?

[This article](http://www.ehow.com/how_2151193_develop-dry-sense-humor.html#ixzz1IGUHd0GX) explains how to develop it, but not what it is.

> **How to Develop a Dry Sense of Humor**
>
> Developing a dry sense of
>   humor can be challenging and fun.
>   Learn how to develop one. If you
>   really want to (and you know you do)
>   then read the article.

Comment: I wish I knew!?

Comment: Considering the date, I think you might have it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here is a relevant definition that says it all:

> **dry**  *adjective*
>   (of a joke or sense of humor) subtle, expressed in a matter-of-fact way, and having the appearance of being unconscious or unintentional:
>   *he delighted his friends with a dry, covert sense of humor*
>
> <sup>[NOAD](http://oxforddictionaries.com/view/entry/m_en_us1242243#m_en_us1242243)</sup>

Answer (score 0):

It should mean being sarcastic and ironic.

Check my answer here: [The word ‘dryly’ as an adverb](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/18840/the-word-dry-as-an-adverb)

Answer (score 0):

The article itself is an example of dry humor.