# Why can humour be dry but not wet?

Tags: word-choice, metaphors

Humour that is presented in a matter of fact way, as it weren't even an attempt to be funny, can be [described as *dry*](https://english.stackexchange.com/a/18908/10974). And any sort of writing or information can be *dry* if it's overly factual in nature.

As far as I know, though, no one uses *wet* to describe obvious humour or information with lots of flourishes.

What would be the right word for the opposite of "dry" in these metaphorical senses?

Or, to ask another way, what one word would you place in these sentences:

> His joke definitely wasn't dry, it was downright _____________!
>
> I thought her lecture would be dry, but it was surprisingly ____________.

When was *dry* first used in this sense, and was *wet* ever used as it's opposite metaphor?

And if I dare ask a "why" question, is there a reason dry is used in this metaphorical sense without having pulled along the obvious antonym?

Comment: The opposite is not "wet". It's "Juicy!"

Comment: As we are talking about humour, I would like to propose that we use the word Moist in those locations, as that word is down right funny!

Comment: _Wet humour_ would be kind of redundant, since the humours are inherently at least **humid**, as their name implies (from Latin _humēre_ ‘to be moist’). I suppose throwing water balloons at people might still adequately be considered _wet humour_, though …

Answer (score 21, accepted):

In this case, *dry* is not the opposite of *wet*, but it means *bare, and lacking adornment*, such as *a dry report*.

[**Etymonline**](http://www.etymonline.com/index.php?term=dry&allowed_in_frame=0), the online etymology dictionary, indicates the word has been used to describe comedy for more than 500 years!

> **dry** O.E. dryge, from P.Gmc. *draugiz, from PIE *dreug-. Meaning "barren" is mid-14c. Of humor or jests, early 15c. (implied in dryly); as "uninteresting, tedious" from 1620s.

As for antonyms, instead of a *dry* lecture, you might sit through a *lively* one.  When applied to jokes, a joke might be *farcical*, or *whimsical*; a comedy routine might be laced with *slapstick*.  One website I found listed [20 distinct forms of humor](http://www.dailywritingtips.com/20-types-and-forms-of-humor/); others in that list which seem "opposite" of *dry* include *hyperbolic, sophomoric, screwball*, but probably not *mordant*.

Comment: Instead of "and perhaps mordant", you should write "but not mordant", in that [mordant](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/mordant) humor often is dry, and dry humor mordant, relationships not held by *hyperbolic, sophomoric, screwball*.

Comment: @jwpat: You make a good point. It's true that some dry humor is rather mordant, and vice versa. However, some mordant humor may be too harsh, caustic and biting to be considered dry. I've decided to change "and perhaps mordant" to "but probably not mordant," which takes your suggestion as an improvement, but acknowledges that two comedians – one mordant, and one dry – still might have two very different acts.

Answer (score 2):

While it is true that *dry* is often used to describe a type of understated humour, and the person who tells a joke  usually delivers the punchline in a  flat [deadpan](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Deadpan) voice. It is false that its most obvious antonym *wet* is never associated with humour. You can in fact ***wet yourself laughing***, which implies that a person laughs so heartily that he or she temporarily loses control of their bladder. Another typical slang expression is *[piss yourself laughing](http://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/british/piss-yourself-laughing)*

A plausible antonym to dry humour could be [vaudeville](http://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/british/vaudeville), as in

> *His joke definitely wasn't dry, it was pure vaudeville!*

Although I still prefer J.R's *slapstick* solution, which typifies the *physical humour/comedy* genre.

Comment: If dry humour is *subtle, understated* or *deadpan*, then its opposites must include *juvenile, unsubtle, obvious* or *slapstick* (or some combination of these).

Comment: @ErikKowal I opted for vaudeville because it involves music, dance, sketches, jokes, etc. It conjures vivacity, non-stop entertainment, variety, and fun. It also sounded good in the OP's sentence.

Comment: My remark was just a general comment. I think *vaudeville* could  be a fine solution; partly, it has the virtue of being fresh and unexpected. :)

Answer (score 0):

While I have not seen such a usage, the term ***juicy*** might convey the sense of the opposite in both these examples.

In regard to humor, the term ***dry*** can convey subtlety and indicate a form that may be an acquired taste, like dry wine or martinis.  ***Juicy*** connotes a more robust and obvious quality.

As to the lecture, the concept of *bare* or *barren* does seem to be the closer meaning. I think ***juicy*** would work there as well.

This is mere opinion and without reference.