# What kind of humour is the antonym of "dry humour"?

Tags: meaning, single-word-requests

And what are the different characteristics of these different forms of humour?

Having looked at the near duplicate question, it does raise some interesting material and supplies possible answers to the question. However it has also made it clear that this is a far more complex subject than I made it sound, and merits a far wider conversation than is possible on this site. The whole question of what we laugh at, and what defines *humour* needs to be considered.

But for anyone interested I recommend reading the duplicate question, and the responses thereto.

Comment: Is this an English *language* question?

Comment: The title is, probably not the body.

Comment: @Josh61 It is all an English language question. How are different forms of humour described? One cannot answer that without defining the characteristics of those types of humour.

Comment: I am not sure that '*a description of different forms of humour*' is on topic, but let see what other users think. The antonym request is just fine, though.

Comment: ***Different forms of humour***: http://www.dailywritingtips.com/20-types-and-forms-of-humor/

Comment: @Josh61 The problem with that list is that the categories cross-analyse. They do not provide a breakdown of the whole. For example *high-brow humour* could also be *dry humour*. It is however interesting that it lists *droll* humour separately from *dry* but next to one another. I think the person who may be able to point to a good treatment on this is [*this man*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Christie_Davies), who I see at local gatherings from time to time. But I think the question of what words such as *droll* are describing should definitely be on-topic.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Why can humour be dry but not wet?](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/75838/why-can-humour-be-dry-but-not-wet)

Answer (score 3):

It could be argued the opposite of *dry humour* is *slapstick*.

*Dry humour* is subtle, indirect humour whereas *slapstick* is more obvious and over the top.

Comment: See also http://english.stackexchange.com/q/75838/9001

Comment: I have read that earlier post, but I'm not sure I understand any more clearly how we describe the opposite of *dry humour* and even if we have a clear idea of what it is. It is without doubt a vast subject.

Comment: Yeah, "slapstick" is what I instantly thought of.  "Burlesque" might also fit, though less precisely, I suspect.